# Eclipse RAP 2.0 application won't start with WebSphere 8.5.5.0

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere, equinox, eclipse-rap

I have an Eclipse RAP application. The web.xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0" 
         id="WebApp">
    <session-config>
        <cookie-config>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
        </cookie-config>
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>

    <servlet id="bridge">  
        <servlet-name>equinoxbridgeservlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.BridgeServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>enableFrameworkControls</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>      
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>commandline</param-name>
            <param-value>-registryMultiLanguage -ws rap -Dhelp.url.prefix="/foobar" -Dhelp.topic.path="topic" -Dhelp.start.page="index.jsp" -Declipse.product=com.XXXXXXXXXXX -console 7272</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>other.info</param-name>
            <param-value>org.eclipse.help</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>    
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>equinoxbridgeservlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

When I start the application, I get the following error in log:

> [11/11/13 10:31:39:136 CET] 00000071 webapp        W
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp initializeStaticFileHandler
>   SRVE0278E: Error while adding servlet mapping --> /*.

I tried this (disable file serving): http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK18713

Any idea about making it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the solution really to disable the fileServing. This however did not work for me with the XMI file. I added the following content to the WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xml file and then it worked:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-ext xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-ext_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
  <enable-file-serving value="false"/>
  <jsp-attribute name="reloadEnabled" value="true"/>
  <jsp-attribute name="reloadInterval" value="10"/>
</web-ext>
```

The real change is the enable-file-serving tag. This seems to work.

Comment: It works. You just have to be sure, that all temp files are deleted inside Websphere. Please try to install the application with a brand new name to see if it is a real caching issue. Rename the WAR to bla.war and try again.

Comment: If you post some question with the config files and the error description, I might be able to help. Do you use the same version?