# Eclipse Help of RAP 2.0 application does not work with WebSphere 8.5.5.0

Tags: eclipse, jsp, websphere, equinox, eclipse-rap

### Problem

As far as I understand in RAP every single servlet request should go through the Equinox Servlet Bridge. This includes the Help pages, which are JSP files inside the org.eclipse.help.webapp plugin.

I have the following Servlet Mapping in the Web.xml:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>equinoxbridgeservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

If I deploy my application into websphere, then I cannot open the help, and I get this error:
[image]

It seems, that WebSphere simply ignores my will, that I want to handle even the "/index.jsp" url with the equinox servlet.

### Already Tried

I tried the ***com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.enableJspMappingOverride*** custom property of the web container, but it did not help.

In the [documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rweb_custom_props.html) it is stated:

> When a url-pattern is defined in the jsp-property-group of the
>   web.xml, file, it is typically mapped to, and handled by the
>   JavaServer Page (JSP) engine. If you have applications that must
>   override this mapping so that they can handle and serve the JSP
>   content themselves, set the
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.enableJspMappingOverride property to true.

I also added the following snippet to the web xml, but it also did not help:

```
  <jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <description>Enables using help webapp JSP pages with Websphere</description>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </jsp-property-group>
  </jsp-config>
```

**Do you have any idea how to make WebSphere to leave my requests with *.jsp URLs alone, and let equinox bridge to make its work?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that the custom property is neccessary, but not enough. I need an extra servlet mapping as [described here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21498109).

So the mapping should look like this:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>equinoxbridgeservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>equinoxbridgeservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: If this additional mapping solves the problem, would you mind adding this snippet to the [RAP FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/RAP/FAQ#How_to_integrate_the_Eclipse_Help_System_in_a_RAP_application.3F)?

Comment: Of course not. Feel free to add it there. One more issue, which would be useful in the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19931614/337621